# R_roi error . Using roi pkg to utility max problem

Tags: r, optimization

i want to use ROI to reproduce the result of following page
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/05/utility-maximization-in-r-using-the-nlcoptim-package/
max u=x^0.5y^0.5 s.t 2x+y<=10

if there something i need to fix to have same result as in the link. thx in advance.

```
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.alabama)
f <- function(x) {
     x[1]^0.5*x[2]^0.5
}
g <- function(x) {
    c(2*x[1]+x[2])
}
nlp <- OP(F_objective(f, n=2), 
          F_constraint(g, dir = rep("<=", 1), rhs = c(100)),
          maximum = TRUE)
(sol <- ROI_solve(nlp, solver = "alabama", start = double(3)))
```

some error display below
Error in rbind(hin.jac(x), bc$hin.jac(x)) :
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In x - lb :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length